# Expand pragma to a comment (for doxygen)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, doxygen

Comments are usually converted to a single white-space before the preprocesor is run. However, there is a compelling use case.

```c
#pragma once   

#ifdef DOXYGEN
  #define DALT(t,f) t
#else
  #define DALT(t,f) f
#endif

#define MAP(n,a,d) \
  DALT ( COMMENT(| n | a | d |) \
       , void* mm_##n = a \
       )

/// Memory map table
/// | name | address | description |
/// |------|---------|-------------|
MAP (reg0  , 0       , foo         )
MAP (reg1  , 8       , bar         )
```

In this example, when the `DOXYGEN` flag is set, I want to generate doxygen markup from the macro. When it isn't, I want to generate the variables. In this instance, the desired behaviour is to generate comments in the macros. Any thoughts about how?

I've tried `/##/` and another example with more indirection

```
#define COMMENT SLASH(/)
#define SLASH(s) /##s
```

neither work.

Comment: If the preprocessor will generate comments, these won't get removed before compillation. And it will fail.

Comment: Doxygen won’t preprocess the file, will it, so it wouldn’t see your macro-generated comments.

Comment: Suggest using one of the 'normal' lead-ins for doxygen info, Then the doxygen info is always in the source file and the compiler will have ignored (as usual) the doxygen info.

Comment: What settings did you use in your Doxyfile? Maybe you should have a look at the ALIASES command as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I beg to differ https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_enable_preprocessing

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think you've missed the point. The comments will only be generated in the case of a doxygen parse, in which case, i very much want them. When its being parsed for compilation, there are no comments

Comment: are the DALT defines correct, look like a mixup of arguments ('t' and 'f'), probably not the problem here though.

Comment: OK — you can tell I don't use Doxygen, then, can't you?  It's also why it's a comment/question, not an answer.  If the output of the preprocessor phase includes what might be comments, the main compilation is not going to be happy.  So, your macro definition will (probably) need to be different depending on whether Doxygen or the compiler proper is going to use the output.  And I see you've said that.  The trouble is that the preprocessor tokenizes input and output, and comment start symbols cannot be concatenated with `##`, and you really are trying to subvert the preprocessor.

Comment: @albert Good spot, corrected

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Note the definition of `DALT`. If `DOXYGEN` is not defined, no comments are to be generated, so normal compilation will succeed as expected. I only want the comments generated during a doxygen parse, which is run independently.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, i am trying to subvert the preprocessor, _for a valid use case_. I don't want the hassle of keeping comments and definitions in sync manually.

Comment: I don't think you can reliably fool a standard preprocessor into generating comment start (or end) symbols.  With a pre-standard preprocessor, you might have been able to do something weird like `#define CAT(x,y) x/**/y` and then use `CAT(/,*)` to start and `CAT(*,/)` to stop the comment (a pre-standard preprocessor probably wouldn't understand `//` comments).  But that doesn't work with standard preprocessors; the comment in the macro definition expands to a space.  Comments have been replaced by spaces (phase 3) before the preprocessor processes macros (phase 4).

Comment: None of `//`, `/*` or `*/` are valid preprocessing tokens so they cannot be created by the `##` operator. Consider 3 lines of source code: `#define CAT(x,y) x##y` — `CAT(/,/) Comment` — `CAT(/,*) Comment CAT(*,/)` — the preprocessor witters `error: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token` (and similarly for the other combinations). If Doxygen doesn't allow this — it might, for all I know, since it is not simply running the normal C preprocessor (because that would strip out all the comments) — then you're stuck.  Consider a separate code/comment generation phase.

Comment: I don't know how practical it would be to jimmy this into a doxygen run, but you _could_ do the text transformation you want with `sed -e 's/^MAP (\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^)]*\))/\/\/\/ | \1 | \2 | \3 |/'`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thats an interesting point, also made by @zwol. A pre doc run with `sed -e 's:#DCOMMENT:DCOMMENT ///:'`, with `#define DCOMMENT` in the code would do it

Comment: Wel a pre doc run is not necessary, you could do it as an INPUT_FILTER in doxygen (see Doxyfile).

Comment: @albert Would you write an example as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In doxygen it is possible to run commands on the sources before they are fed into the doxygen kernel. In the Doxyfile there are some FILTER possibilities. In this case: `INPUT_FILTER` the line should read:

`INPUT_FILTER = "sed -e 's%^ *MAP *(\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^)]*\))%/// | \1 | \2 | \3 |%'"`

Furthermore the entire `#if` construct can disappear and one, probably, just needs:

`#define MAP(n,a,d) void* mm_##n = a`

Answer (score 2):

The ISO C standard describes the output of the preprocessor as a stream of *preprocessing tokens*, not text.  Comments are not preprocessing tokens; they are stripped from the input before tokenization happens.  Therefore, within the standard facilities of the language, it is fundamentally impossible for preprocessing output to contain comments or anything that resembles them.

In particular, consider

```
#define EMPTY
#define NOT_A_COMMENT_1(text) /EMPTY/EMPTY/ text
#define NOT_A_COMMENT_2(text) / / / text
NOT_A_COMMENT_1(word word word)
NOT_A_COMMENT_2(word word word)
```

After translation phase 4, both the fourth and fifth lines of the above will both become the six-token sequence

```
[/][/][/][word][word][word]
```

where square brackets indicate token boundaries.  There isn't any such thing as a `//` token, and therefore there is nothing you can do to make the preprocessor produce one.

Now, the ISO C standard doesn't specify the behavior of doxygen.  However, if doxygen is reusing a preprocessor that came with someone's C compiler, the people who wrote that preprocessor probably thought textual preprocessor output should be, above all, an accurate reflection of the token sequence that the "compiler proper" would receive.  That means it will forcibly insert spaces where necessary to make separate tokens remain separate.  For instance, with `test.c` the above example,

```
$ gcc -E test.c
...
/ / / word word word
/ / / word word word
```

(I have elided some irrelevant chatter above the output we're interested in.)

If there is a way around this, you are most likely to find it in the doxygen manual.  There might, for instance, be configuration options that teach it that certain macros should be understood to define symbols, and what symbols those are, and what documentation they should have.